# unrecognized selector sent to instance Error when trying to setTarget action

Tags: ios, swift, selector

I'm trying to put a Listener for click on button. I've searched for some similar issues and still didn't eliminate crash.

I inherited UIButton to pass an extra parameter to TouchUpInside event

```
 class ButtonWithRunnableContainer : UIButton{
        var runnable : Runnable!
 }
```

Now I add this button programmatically :

```
public class FloatingButtonsController : NSObject{

 init (parentView:UIView!){
        super.init()
        self.parentView = parentView
 }
//...

public func registerButton (type: Int, runnable: Runnable!){

        let button = ButtonWithRunnableContainer (frame: CGRect(rect))
        button.runnable = runnable        
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: name), forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        parentView.addSubview(button)        
    }
```

and here's where it crashes :

```
    func buttonAction(sender : ButtonWithRunnableContainer!){
        sender.runnable()
    }
}
```

The error is : terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[orthodoxprayernew.FloatingButtonsController buttonAction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fee13d88a50'

Comment: is buttonAction declared in FLoatingButtonsController ? If the method contains sender param , you need to do buttonAction: instead of buttonAction

Comment: @TejaNandamuri what does that mean?